# Drupal Content Generation

Tags: drupal

I have a client who needs information scraped from a site -- simple enough task. But it's a little bit more complicated than that. It looks like the content on the site is getting generated dynamically, and that's making it difficult to scrape the data I need.

I need to check if a specific item is in stock or not.

An example can be found here: http://www.maccosmetics.com/product/13854/36182/Products/Makeup/Lips/Lipstick/Giambattista-Valli-Lipstick

The issue comes in when I view source.

As you can see, there's a list with items that have the class "inv-status" and then a number. The source shows all these inventory statuses, even though the actual page only shows the list item stating that the item is sold out.

My first thought is "Oh, they must be masking this with JS somehow...."

Near the bottom of the source code I found some JSON containing what seems to be information about the product(s). Scrolling down I see something called "INVENTORY_STATUS:1", which I can only assume means the item is in stock. I tried searching for "INVENTORY_STATUS:7" and it only came with one result -- but the result has nothing to do with the product I'm looking for. It looked like it had something to do with a different product.

I'm thoroughly confused and I don't know what to do next. If any of you can help steer me in the right direction here, it would be greatly appreciated.

I hope this post is clear enough, if not, I can answer your questions.

Comment: [Screenshot](https://gyazo.com/2ec1dac9269b50e7a495001e55d7444a)  of some of the source code here.

Comment: A quick non-programming note: If your client is in business with the owners of this website, you could just aks them; I'm sure they'll be glad to help you if it creates more exposure and higher sales for their product.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That didn't even cross my mind... duh